# Stacked UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm new in iOS and I'm working with Storyboards.

I have an application with some views.

My rootViewController (1) is a UINavigationController that connects to other views. At one point in the application (2), I include a component (SWRevealViewController, Facebook Side Menu Style) that is an instance of UINavigationController, so I have two UINavigationControllers nested within each other. I want to remove or change the first UINavigationController by the new one (2), and just have only one. All views are accessed via custom segues.

[Detailed Image Here](http://i44.tinypic.com/2rrkqaq.png)

I think the solution is to change the rootViewController before loading the view (2), and set the second UINavigationController as the main of the application.

[Detailed Image Here](http://i39.tinypic.com/4vjmna.png)

I tried to solve it accessing by:

```
[UIApplication delegate].window.rootViewController = myController;
```

but I only have `nil` or a empty window.

I read many post that the solution could be in my AppDelegate in the method 
 
`- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (UIApplication *) application` 
  I can't understand how to apply it to my structure, because that method is called when the application is launched.

I think that my workflow application is wrong.
Any feedback or help is welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to change the root view controller from another controller, but your code is wrong. It should be:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController = myController;
```

If you're doing this action from a controller whose view is currently on screen, you can do it this way instead:

```
self.view.window.rootViewController = myController;
```

This should work as long as myController has been properly instantiated.

Comment: I tried to put these statements in my controller, but I get a black screen:

self.view.window.rootViewController = self;
[self.view.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: In addition, the value of self.view.window.rootViewController is null

Comment: @FrandelaRosa Is self.view.window also null? It shouldn't be if the controller you have that code in has its view on screen.

Comment: It's works! I have created a new instance of my controller using storyboards with [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id"] and passed to my [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly remove (1) or off load it into another view controller that is hidden and once the user goes back to a point where you want (1) back you can load it back in. This could be done in the `- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (UIApplication *) application`.